# Is it possible to register two GCM instances in application?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm creating a library that uses GCM for receiving messages. But what if i need to use GCM also in app that uses my library? Seems like i need to register two GCM instances in one project.

I'm trying to register GCM in that way

```
try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                storeRegistrationId(MainActivity.this, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                Timber.e("\"Error :\" + ex.getMessage()");

            }
```

And in my library register with context of Application

```
 gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
```

But only last registered GCM is working. 
So, is there any possibility to register two instances?

Comment: Are you using the same sender ID for both registrations? You should use different SENDER IDs.

Comment: Another option, though I am not sure of your use case, is to use a single sender ID and handle it based on information in the `data` bundle. For example, you can have a String called "my_action" that would say which module (library or app) should handle the new message.